# how to break string that has format like "java method signature" into part?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, split

I have a complex strings like the following format pattern:

```
(Command)(Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_n)
```

Example: **PADDING_LEFT(LAST_USE_COUNTER(1450,5),5,0)**

I want to split them as following:

Command:PADDING_LEFT

Parameter_1:LAST_USE_COUNTER(1450,5)

Parameter_2: 5

Parameter_3: 0

Is there a way to a break such string?

Comment: How are parameters defined? As the self defined pattern and a literal?

Comment: Have you looked at using a tool like Antlr http://www.antlr.org

Comment: Take a look at [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828) and let us know what specific problems you're having splitting it (which should include a [mcve]).

Comment: The nested function call makes this a little more complicated than simply splitting the string or using a regex.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The question should still be more specific though (and specify the pattern more precisely).

Comment: @Dukeling My comment was for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go down the regex route. A more robust approach could be to use a Java syntax parser, such as [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/):

```
MethodCallExpr bs =
    (MethodCallExpr) JavaParser.parseExpression
                    ("PADDING_LEFT(LAST_USE_COUNTER(1450,5),5,0)");
System.out.println(bs.getName());
List<Expression> arguments = bs.getArguments();
for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.printf("Argument_%d: %s%n", (i + 1), arguments.get(i));
}
```